# Does not show the image received from the database

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express, multer

I'm doing a mini exercise using the following tools: React, Node.js, Express and MongoDB.

I am trying to upload an image to the database and then display it using a form.

The back end code is as follows:

```
const multer = require('multer')

const storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, 'public/uploads/')
  },
  filename: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, file.originalname)
  }
})

const upload = multer({ storage })

app.post('/upload', upload.single('file'), async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const newFile = new File({
      filename: req.file.originalname,
      contentType: req.file.mimetype,
      destination: req.file.destination,
      fileName: req.file.filename,
      path: req.file.path,
      buffer: req.file.buffer,
      fieldname: req.file.fieldname,
      data: req.file.buffer
    })
    // Guardar el documento en la base de datos
    const savedImage = await newFile.save()
    res.json(savedImage)
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error)
    res.status(500).send('Error al subir el archivo')
  }
})

app.get('/image/:id', async (req, res, next) => {
  const { id } = req.params

  try {
    const file = await File.findById(id)

    if (file) {
      res.set('Content-Type', file.contentType)
      res.send(file.buffer)
    } else {
      res.status(500).send('Error al buscar la imagen')
    }
  } catch (error) {
    next(error)
  }
})
```

The front end code is as follows:

```
function App() {
  const { register, handleSubmit } = useForm();
  const [imagen , setImagen] = useState(null);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);

  const onSubmit = async (data) => {
    setLoading(true);
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("file", data.file[0]);
    try {
      const response = await axios.post('http://localhost:3001/upload', formData, {
        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data' },
    });
      const res = await axios.get(`http://localhost:3001/image/${response.data.id}`);
      setImagen(res.data);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    } finally {
      setLoading(false);
    }
  };
  
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
        <input type="file" {...register("file")} />
        <button type="submit" disabled={loading}>{loading ? "Cargando..." : "Enviar"}</button>
      </form> 
      {imagen && (
        <div>
          <h1>Imagen:</h1>
          <img src={`http://localhost:3001/${imagen.path}`} alt={imagen.fileName} width="500" height="600" />
        </div>
      )
      }
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

The code itself works but I don't understand why it doesn't show me the images.

Does anyone know where the error is or why it doesn't work?
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

If you use `multer` with `storage: multer.diskStorage(...)`, the files will be uploaded to the disk, and `req.file.buffer` will *not* be filled. Filling it would mean that the file must be kept in memory and that's what `diskStorage` is meant to prevent.

To see the file contents, you must load the file from disk again. This could be done as

```js
fs.readFileSync(req.file.path)
```

but then, again, this loads the entire file into memory. However, this is probably something you cannot avoid unless you can stream the file into your mongodb.